# Linq query using join

Tags: c#, sql, linq, join

Can anybody help me with this sql query how can I write it in LINQ

```
SELECT FGA_Vin.vin,
FROM FGA_Vin INNER JOIN Info_Global 
ON  FGA_Vin.Vin='XXXXXXXXXX' AND
    FGA_Vin.NHard=dbo.Info_Global.NHard AND
    Info_Global.NVerHard like '%'+FGA_Vin.NVerHard and
    Info_Global.NVerSoft like '%'+FGA_Vin.NVerSoft
inner join Info_Associa
on Info_Associa.KeyJoined = Info_Global.NomeFile
```

I have tried

```
var reportdata =    from Vin in FGA_Vin 
                                join Global in Info_Globals 
                                on Vin.NHard equals Global.NHard 
                                && on Global.NVerHard equals Vin.NVerHard

                                select new XElement("flash",
                                    new XElement("Vin", Vin.Vin),
                                    new XElement("ModelType", Global.Model_Type)
                                );
```

but when I add "&& on Global.NVerHard equals Vin.NVerHard" then it's all in red.

how can I compare different column of different tables using join if the && does not respond

Thanks

Comment: This is not a write my code site. What have you tried so far ?

Comment: I corrected my questions Joachim. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe something like this:

```
var result= 
    (
        from v in db.FGA_Vin
        from i in db.Info_Global
            .Where(w=>
                w.NHard==v.NHard &&
                w.NVerHard.Contains(v.NVerHard) &&
                w.NVerSoft.Contains(v.NVerSoft)
            )
        join ia in db.Info_Associa
            on i.NomeFile equals ia.KeyJoined
        where v.Vin=="XXXXXXXXXX"
        select v.vin
    ).ToList();
```

Where `db` is the linq data context

Answer (score 0):

```
var reportdata =    
                (from Vin in FGA_Vin 
                join Global in Info_Globals on new {Vin.NHard, Vin.NVerHard } equals {Global.NHard, Global.NVerHard }
                join Info_Associa on Info_Global.NomeFile equals Info_Associa.KeyJoined
                where Info_Global.NVerHard.Contains(FGA_Vin.NVerHard)
                where Info_Global.NVerSoft.Contains(FGA_Vin.NVerSoft)
                select new XElement("flash",
                    new XElement("Vin", Vin.Vin),
                    new XElement("ModelType", Global.Model_Type)
                );
```

Comment: but what if I have to compare some columns in different tables with LIKE? I mean if you check my sql query you will see I have to check many things

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:-

```
var result =
    (
        db.FGA_Vin.SelectMany(v => db.Info_Global
            .Where(w =>
                w.NHard == v.NHard &&
                w.NVerHard.Contains(v.NVerHard) &&
                w.NVerSoft.Contains(v.NVerSoft)
            ), (v, i) => new {v, i})
            .Join(db.Info_Associa, @t => i.NomeFile, ia => ia.KeyJoined, (@t, ia) => new {@t, ia})
            .Where(@t => v.Vin == "XXXXXXXXXX")
            .Select(@t => v.vin)
        ).ToList();
```